# .$blockUI to show current status

Tags: jquery

I need some advice on this.

I want to use `blockUI` to show the user what the system is currently doing, as the update query will take sometime to complete. However, no message is showing.

In script.php

```
echo json_encode(array("update table 1"));
$objUpdate  = $ocidb_srms ->ORAUpdateRecord($strTable1, $strCommand, $strCondition);
echo json_encode(array("update table 1 done"));

echo json_encode(array("update table 2"));
$objUpdate  = $ocidb_srms ->ORAUpdateRecord($strTable2, $strCommand, $strCondition);
echo json_encode(array("update table 2 done"));

echo json_encode(array("true"));
```

in jquery.html

```
$.blockUI();
$.ajax({
url: script.php,
dataType: "json",
success: function(data){
$.blockUI({ message: data[0] });
if (data[0] == "TRUE"){
alert(done);
}
if (data[0] == "FALSE"){
alert("Error");
}
$.unblockUI();
}
});
```

Comment: What it looks like  you are trying to do is not possible. You can't have multiple responses with one ajax call. You will perhaps have to make a ajax call for each action and update blockui accordingly. Also blockui doesn't need to be json to update the message. You can use plain text in the response.

Comment: What shall the correct plugin to use if I need this function?

Comment: It's not really the plugin. It's your structure. I don't know how your php file is setup but I would make functions for the updates and call those functions via the ajax. you can have blockui active during that time. That would be the easiest.